# Ordering pandas dataframe column in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have tried to find a specific answer to this question but no luck.

I have created a groupby dataframe where I have found the mean rating of a series of movies. I now have the movie id's as the index, but I want to order all the ratings with the highest rating at the top, lowest at the bottom. I have tried the sort and sort_value function to no avail.

```
r_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'unix_timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_csv(
    'http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k/u.data', 
    sep='\t', names=r_cols)

grouped_ratings=ratings['rating'].groupby(ratings['movie_id'])
average_rating=grouped_ratings.mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to sort by rating in descending order use

```
average_rating.sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: `df = df.sort_value('col1', ascending=False)` ?

Comment: I have changed my answer to reflect the variable names in the question

Comment: Thankyou very much, if say I had multiple columns in my dataframe, i would just call them out by name as you have shown above ie. 'col1'?

Comment: That's correct. just use df.sort_values('col1', 'col2') etc.